# Sensor driver for Inertial Labs GPS-Aided INS-B, INS-P, INS-D

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a user of INS-D (Dual Antenna) product. Now I want to use this product in ROS, but the driver connection (http://wiki.ros.org/Inertial%20Labs%20GPS-Aded%20INS-B%20INS-P%20INS-D) of this product has been unavailable. I want to know when to update?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324109/sensor-driver-for-inertial-labs-gps-aided-ins-b,-ins-p,-ins-d/) by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-28**:
Related: #q291538.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-28**:
Never used it -- and the documentation is in Chinese -- but a quick google finds: [albus12138/ros_ilins_driver](https://github.com/albus12138/ros_ilins_driver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the driver provided by Inertial Labs.[Sensor driver for INS-D](https://us.inertiallabs.com:31443/projects/INS/repos/inertiallabs_ros_package/browse)

---

Originally posted by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) with karma: 40 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0